# Duplicate input id issue in popover with forms

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using Bootstrap 3 and loading a filter form inside the popover.
In order to create a CSS-based checkbox effect, the HTML needs to be structured in a specific way (as in the jsfiddle example)

I'm grabbing the html from a hidden div that contains the form and loading it inside popover. The form counts on the label feature that allows an input of certain id to be checked when referenced from label for="" attribute.

But due to the popover allowing the original html to exist, there's a duplicate ID problem. Because of this, the checkbox does not get checked even when the label is clicked on.

Any suggestion you have for troubleshooting this would be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
$.noConflict();

function filterToggle (title, toggle, html) {
  toggle.popover({
    html: true, 
    placement: "auto",
    content: function() {
      return html.html();
    },
    title: title+'<button type="button" id="close" class="close"></button>',
    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-title"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
  });
};
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  filterToggle(
    'Filter Title',
    $('#popover-toggle'), 
    $('#popover-content-html')
  );
});
```

```css
.popover { max-width:500px; }
.checkbox input[type=checkbox], .checkbox-inline input[type=checkbox], .radio input[type=radio], .radio-inline input[type=radio] { margin-left:0; }

div.checkbox label:before {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
div.checkbox input:checked + label:before {
  border-color: green;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 16px;
}

div.checkbox {
  position: relative;
}
div.checkbox label {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
div.checkbox label:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.checkbox input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: -9999px !important;
}
div.checkbox input.hidden + label {
  padding-left: 0;
}
div.checkbox input.hidden + label:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="popover-content-html" class="hidden">
  <form>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="checkbox-1"/>
      <label for="checkbox-1" class="control-panel">Bike</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Motorcycle" id="checkbox-2"/>
      <label for="checkbox-2" class="control-panel">Motorcycle</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" id="checkbox-3"/>
      <label for="checkbox-3" class="control-panel">Car</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="popover-toggle">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the form when popover is shown and copy this form from popover content. After hiding popover you can prepend copied form to previous div so there is always one form.

```js
$.noConflict();

var form = jQuery('#popover-content-html').find('form');

function filterToggle(title, toggle, html) {
  toggle.popover({
    html: true,
    placement: "auto",
    content: function() {
      return html.html();
    },
    title: title + '<button type="button" id="close" class="close"></button>',
    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-title"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
  });
};
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  filterToggle(
    'Filter Title',
    $('#popover-toggle'),
    $('#popover-content-html')
  );
});

jQuery('#popover-toggle').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
  form.remove();
  form = jQuery('.popover-content').find('form');
});
jQuery('#popover-toggle').on('hidden.bs.popover', function() {
  form.prependTo('#popover-content-html');
});
```

```css
.popover { max-width:500px; }
.checkbox input[type=checkbox], .checkbox-inline input[type=checkbox], .radio input[type=radio], .radio-inline input[type=radio] { margin-left:0; }

div.checkbox label:before {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
div.checkbox input:checked + label:before {
  border-color: green;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 16px;
}
div.checkbox {
  position: relative;
}
div.checkbox label {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
div.checkbox label:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.checkbox input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: -9999px !important;
}
div.checkbox input.hidden + label {
  padding-left: 0;
}
div.checkbox input.hidden + label:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="popover-content-html" class="hidden">
  <form>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="checkbox-1"/>
      <label for="checkbox-1" class="control-panel">Bike</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Motorcycle" id="checkbox-2"/>
      <label for="checkbox-2" class="control-panel">Motorcycle</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" id="checkbox-3"/>
      <label for="checkbox-3" class="control-panel">Car</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="popover-toggle">Click Me!</button>
```